# How to use a number to replace a string value in weka using fiter?

Tags: string, csv, weka

Now I have a question. I need to use weka fiter to handle the data which is the object of Instances class.The codes are here.

```
CSVLoader loader=new CSVLoader();
loader.setSource(new File(path to file.csv));
Instances data=loader.getDataSet();
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

LibSVM classifier=new LibSVM();
Evaluation eval=new Evaluation(data);
classifier.setOptions(LIBSVM_OPTIONS);
eval.crossValidateModel(classifier,data,10,new Random(1));
```

When I run the code, it gave the information:weka.classifer.functions.LibSVM:Cannot handle string attributes!

Some attributes are string type.

I want to use weka filter to handle the data object.There are some string elements in the data.The raw csv file data is like this.

```
title1,title2,title3,title4,title5,title6
123,   122,   112,   121,   121,   123
121,   123,   121,   123,   inf,   121
123,   inf,   123,   123,   123,   123
```

Of course, the csv file is saved in excel.Its name is like abc.csv. There are a lot of numbers in the csv file. But there are some string type elements, for example, inf. Now I have to use weka filter to use a large number to replace the string inf in the csv file. I don't need to handle the csv file first using OPENcsv package and then using CSVLoader to load the new csv file that contains numbers. I need to use weka filter to handle that after using CSVLoader and creating the Instances object.

I searched a lot about it but I can't find the answer. So can I use a weka filter to use a large number to replace the string inf in csv file? Then all attributes are numeric type.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually want to treat 'inf' values as very large numbers for modelling purposes, or would it be better to ignore them?

Comment: I just want to use a large number to replace the string inf. And then the column can be converted to numeric type. So I can handle the data using LibSVM. Because then the columns of data will be all numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one specific string that you need to be able to substitute - for example the string `"inf"` - then according to the [CSVLoader class documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html) you should be able to handle this using the `setMissingValue` method. By setting the missing value string to `inf`, you will import all `inf` values as missing values. If all the rest of the data in a column is numeric, that column should then get correctly imported as a numeric attribute.

If you really want Weka to treat these replaced values as a large number, you can then apply [`weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant.html). However I would check whether that really makes sense in modelling terms - what does it actually mean when one of the attributes is `inf`?. At a guess, if the size of the value you substitute affects the result of the model then you probably shouldn't do it.

If your data contains more than one different string that you need to handle, I don't see a straightforward way of doing it with Weka filters. However instead of passing a file to `CSVLoader`, the docs say you can also pass a `java.io.InputStream`. If you can't process and save a new csv file for some reason, perhaps you could write a subclass of InputStream that filters out the string values as it reads the file.

Comment: When the second line of codes above runs, there are two columns which are given the string attribute in the example. So can the attribute type of string be converted to numeric type using weka fiter?

Comment: can I set multiple Missing values?